Handle background processing once
I have a Blazor Interactive Server app running on Azure App Services. It scales out/in with a minimum of 2 instances and it got up to 5 once.
In the app I have a BackgroundService that I use to send emails, synchronize with an external service, mark events closed when they have hit their end date, etc. It runs once every 5 minutes and when I signal it (changed something I want to get synchronized ASAP).
If there was one instance then this is a piece of cake. I read all the pending items from the DB and act on them and/or update the database record.
But with 2+ instances there's the issue of sending 2 emails. I can set things up so I get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when I've sent it twice but by the time I get that it's too late - I've sent 2 emails.
And with Azure spinning up new instances and shutting down old ones to run Windows update, etc. I can't find any way to identify one instance to be the only one running. Plus I need to signal the worker in every instance.
So, is there some way I can create a semaphore or something in the database. Where it then is the only background thread allowed to run for 2 minutes (time limit in case Azure then shuts down that server)? Or some other approach?
Because all the work this worker does is based off the database, if any one instance is processing the background items, it will get all items wanted by all instances. So there's no need to signal the other instances when one instance is done processing.
Update: Based on the comments below, let me add a bit.

Leadership election - yes that's what I am leaning toward. Using a DB table for this. But it can't be a permanent decision because server instances get closed down. In addition, I need any instance able to kick off the process. So I think maybe more like what goes on with network communication where each, via the DB, tries to grab a semaphore when it wants to run. And if it wins, runs. But the big question then is, how specifically to do this.
Making the DB a message queue for some of this works. That adds complexity though where it becomes try to take assignment of an item. And if an item was grabbed 5 minutes ago, but is still held, then assume that instance died. However a big problem with this is the most important set of items must be processed in order. Item 1 causes an object to be added to the database that item 2 needs. So more complex, tricky re-try logic, and possible stalling of the queue. So not wild on this approach.
I am considering having a function do this. But that adds the problem of signaling it (I assume Azure has a way to do this). Bigger problem, I now have a single point of failure. Or I have 2 functions, in different data centers, and then I'm back with this original problem.

That's why this is so tricky. For some of the key items they need to be processed in order, I want to have multiple instances available to run, and I need the ability for all app server instances to be able to kick off the processing.
On the good news side, if an instance is signaled and another instance is running, that works. The second instance can do nothing.

Have your instances hold a leadership-election and the winner is the one responsible for running the BackgroundService. (While Azure App Services instances cannot communicate with each other directly (i.e. over HTTP) they can still use other shared stated / shared persistence media like your RDBMS or a Redis instance (or even the shared filesystem) to exchange messages and be-aware of each other and coordinate that way.

Or write your queue such that it can be processed by multiple queue processors, which means a process has to mark an item as in progress in a way that only one process can do so. And then mark it complete when done.

Another approach is to simply not use any kind of automatic background-job-runner/scheduler, and instead use an external cron-job (e.g. Azure Logic Apps) to make  scheduler-requests and let the Azure App Service load-balancers decide which instance gets to run the job each time.

The queue processing workers shouldn't need to know about one another nor communicate amongst themselves. Do your workers use transactions? uplock hints? readpast hints?

@AlwaysLearning Azure SQL doesn’t support distributed transactions, unfortunately.  I lament the slow death of X/Open XA.

In fact the easiest way to do this is to use existing technology. For example NServiceBus... It handles all that you need under the hood without having to roll your own. Otherwise, as you say, any of the solutions are complex with maintainability issues.

You can perhaps use sp_getapplock to lock the function from other threads.

There is a beautiful library that does exactly this - DistributedLock. Works great.

Here you have the SQL Server database objects of a distributed keyed mutex implementation:
CREATE TABLE dbo.resource_locks
(
    resource_id varchar(256) CONSTRAINT pk_resource_locks PRIMARY KEY,
    expires_at datetime NOT NULL,
    session_id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.try_acquire_lock
    @resource_id varchar(256),
    @expires_at datetime,
    @session_id uniqueidentifier OUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @session_id = NEWID()
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO dbo.resource_locks(resource_id, expires_at, session_id)
    VALUES (@resource_id, @expires_at, @session_id);
    -- lock acquired
    RETURN 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    /* 2627 is primary key violation error */
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() != 2627 THROW

    UPDATE dbo.resource_locks
    SET
        expires_at = @expires_at,
        session_id = @session_id
    WHERE 
        resource_id = @resource_id
        /* It acquires expired locks only */
        AND  expires_at < GETUTCDATE()
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    BEGIN
        -- failed to acquire lock. the lock is still active or the lock was just released (deleted)
        SET @session_id = NULL
        RETURN 1
    END
    
    -- expired lock acquired
    RETURN 0;
END CATCH

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.try_renew_lock
    @resource_id varchar(256),
    @expires_at datetime,
    @session_id uniqueidentifier
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE dbo.resource_locks
SET expires_at = @expires_at
WHERE
    resource_id = @resource_id
    AND session_id = @session_id
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    -- failed to renew lock. 
    RETURN 1
END
-- lock renewed
RETURN 0

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.try_release_lock
    @resource_id nvarchar(384),
    @session_id uniqueidentifier
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DELETE FROM dbo.resource_locks
WHERE
    resource_id = @resource_id
    AND session_id = @session_id;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    -- failed to release lock. 
    RETURN 1
END
-- lock released
RETURN 0

GO

Locks are stored in dbo.resource_locks table. Locks expire at a specific datetime. After a lock expires other sessions can acquire the lock on the resource resource_id. In this way, if a process exits without releasing the lock, other processes can acquire the lock after it expires.
When one needs to get a distributed mutex for a given key,  calls dbo.try_acquire_lock passing the key as resource_id and the appropriate expires_at datetime. If the stored procedure can acquire the lock it will return 0 and will set @session_id output parameter. If it fails to acquire the lock it will return 1 and @session_id will be NULL.
If the operation to be done under the mutex can end after the mutex expires you need to renew the lock before it expires, passing the new expiration date and the session_id that you get when you acquired the lock.
At the end of the operation you should release the lock by calling dbo.try_release_lock stored procedure
